# my request contains a parenthesis error, however no

Tags: sql, oracle, qgis

I have an error (1- near"(":syntax error) when writing this formula, yet I do not see a "("missing, in advance thank you for your help.

```
select_last_tourn AS (
                SELECT fc.ID as FC_ID,fc.IDENTIFIANT, t.ID as TOUR_ID, t.DATE_TOURNEE,
                               max (t.DATE_TOURNEE) OVER (ORDER BY t.DATE_TOURNEE) DT_LAST_TOURNEE
                FROM RSF_FICHE_11 fc
                lEFT JOIN mnt ON fc.ID=mnt.ID1
```

Comment: Remove the first line `select_last_tourn AS (`. And... that parenthesis is unbalanced.

Comment: I put everything on the same line, on the other hand why do you say: "that parenthesis is unbalanced"?

Comment: As it is, if you count left parenthesis you'll find `3`. If you count right parenthesis you'll find `2`.

Answer (score 1):

If you using CTE, then try this:

```
WITH select_last_tourn AS (
                SELECT fc.ID as FC_ID,fc.IDENTIFIANT, mnt.ID as TOUR_ID, mnt.DATE_TOURNEE,
                max (mnt.DATE_TOURNEE) OVER (ORDER BY mnt.DATE_TOURNEE) DT_LAST_TOURNEE
                FROM RSF_FICHE_11 fc
                lEFT JOIN mnt ON fc.ID=mnt.ID1
                           )

SELECT * FROM select_last_tourn
```

Comment: In this query you using alias naming with t , for example t.ID, t.DATE_TOURNEE but where this defined? maybe this need to replace with alias mnt? I have edited query, try it

Answer (score 0):

Following your remarks, I made new tests.
Without success, I put the rest of the request.

```
WITH mnt AS (
select cast(mt.ID as numeric) as ID, cast(mt.ID1 as numeric) as ID1,
format_date(t.DATE_TOURNEE,'dd/MM/yyyy') as DATE_TOURNEE  
FROM MR_P mt 
LEFT JOIN RF_TOURNEE t ON mt.ID=t.ID
)
SELECT fc.ID as FC_ID,fc.IDENTIFIANT, mnt.ID as TOUR_ID, mnt.DATE_TOURNEE,max (mnt.DATE_TOURNEE) OVER (ORDER BY mnt.DATE_TOURNEE) DT_LAST_TOURNEE
FROM RF_Fiches fc 
LEFT JOIN mnt ON fc.ID=mnt.ID1;
```

[erreur sql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuiOh.jpg)